# smart tagging feature for discussion topics

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to implement smart tagging that detects the relevant tags from keywords in the discussion or title?

Comment: Remember that good tags are not used to describe what a post *contains*, but what it is *about*, only this allow tags to bring a useful information and allows pertinent posts classification.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a need for this. Search engines search on tags and content so they will work just fine, and that is one of the key factors.

Is there a specific instance which has led you need a way to auto-tag? Here on Security we have pretty good tags, most of which have wiki explanations.